# How to mock API client created inside a test class?

Tags: node.js, jasmine, jestjs, sinon

I have a component class as below which create the rest and websocket connections using a third party npm module. I could change the Component.constructor to accept the module as a dependency so that I can inject a mock version during my Jest testing. But I read about Mocks with Jest, I thought I want to try it, but I cannot seem to understand how to intercept Api.Rest() and Api.Websocket return values.

```
// component.ts
import * as Api from 'npm-module'
import * as wait from 'wait-for-stuff' // actual npm module
export class Component {
    private _rest:any;
    private _websocket:any;
    public events = new EventEmitter();
    constructor() {
        // I want to intecept the return value of
        // Api.Rest() and Api.Websocket() to use mock versions.
        this._rest = new Api.Rest();
        this._websocket = new Api.Websocket();

        this._init();
    }

    private _init() {
        // so that when do stuff with this._rest and this._websocket;
        // I can control what is the expected results during test
        this._websocket.onUpdate((data) => {
            events.emit('update', data);
        });
        var value = wait.for.promise(this._rest.getSomething());
    }
}
```

Do I have to use another test library like Sinon or Jasmine?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simplified working example to get you started:

```
// @ts-ignore
import * as Api from 'npm-module';  // <= (ts-ignore since "npm-module" doesn't exist)
import EventEmitter from 'events';

jest.mock('npm-module', () => {
  const getSomethingMock = jest.fn();  // <= always return...
  const onUpdateMock = jest.fn();  // <= ...the same mocks...
  return {
    Rest: () => ({ getSomething: getSomethingMock }),
    Websocket: () => ({ onUpdate: onUpdateMock })
  }
},
{ virtual: true });  // <= (use virtual since "npm-module" doesn't exist)

class Component {
  private _rest: any;
  private _websocket: any;
  public events = new EventEmitter();
  constructor() {
    this._rest = new Api.Rest();
    this._websocket = new Api.Websocket();
    this._init();
  }

  private _init() {
    this._websocket.onUpdate((data) => {  // <= ...so that this onUpdate...
      this.events.emit('update', data);
    });
  }
}

test('Component', () => {
  const component = new Component();
  const listener = jest.fn();
  component.events.on('update', listener);
  const onUpdate = new Api.Websocket().onUpdate;  // <= ...is the same as this one
  const onUpdateArrowFunction = onUpdate.mock.calls[0][0];  // <= get the arrow function passed to it
  onUpdateArrowFunction('mock data');  // <= now call the function
  expect(listener).toHaveBeenCalledWith('mock data');  // Success!
});
```

---

**Details**

`Jest` takes over the `require` system and allows you to specify what you want it to return when a module is required (note that TypeScript `import` statements get compiled to `require` calls).

One way to mock a module is to create a [manual mock](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks#mocking-node-modules) by creating a file at `__mocks__/npm-module.ts` that contains your mock.

Another way (show above) is to use [`jest.mock`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options) and pass it a module factory function.

Whenever the module is required during the test `Jest` will return the mocked module instead.

Note that the example above always returns the same mock for `getSomething` and `onUpdate` so those mock functions can be retrieved during the test.

Also note the use of [`mockFn.mock.calls`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api#mockfnmockcalls) to retrieve this arrow function:

```
(data) => {
  this.events.emit('update', data);
}
```

...which gets passed to `onUpdate`.  Once it has been retrieved, it can be called directly which triggers the listener as expected.

Comment: Just to report back, I get `TypeError: Api.Rest is not a constructor` for this line `this._rest = new Api.Rest()` in Component class. So it is not working for me, I am still trying desperately.